# Mapping 12th mouse button in Blender?

Tags: mouse, blender

I am on Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit, hooked up the Mad Catz R.A.T.7 mouse, however i am unable to map "Aim" button (code 12) in Blender. Everything else maps perfectly!

Following code was added to Xorg.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Mad Catz Inc. R.A.T. 7"
MatchProduct "Mad Catz Mad Catz R.A.T.7 Mouse"
MatchIsPointer "true"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Driver "evdev"
Option "Buttons" "17"
Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 7 6 12 0 0 0 16 17"
Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection
```

But "Aim" button with code 12 is not wanting to map. When running xev from terminal - pressing aim button shows code 12, so button itself works, just dont like to be mapped.

Please advise, maybe someone has solved this already. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of [wm_event_types.h](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/windowmanager/wm_event_types.h$60) I see definitions for seven mouse buttons. I expect blender would need to be adjusted to respond properly to more buttons.

I would suggest reporting it as a bug at [developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org) either as a specific mouse model not supported or limited mouse button support.